# Find the complex $a$,such $x^2-x+a|x^{13}+x+90$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

If $a$ be complex number,such 
$$x^2-x+a|x^{13}+x+90$$find $a$

I think  it is equality if $r^2-r+a=0$  $$\Longrightarrow r^{13}+r+90=0$$,find the $a$

Comment: Well then I have misunderstood the nature of the question. Clearly $a=r-r^2$ the other root being $1-r$ so you need to find and $r$ such that $r$ and $1-r$ are both solutions to $x^{13}+x+90=0$. I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following verifies the uniqueness of the solution $a=2$ proposed in previous answers, by brute force (and some [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)-assistance)... Let $x_{1,2}$ be the roots of $x^2-x+a$, then by [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas) $x_1+x_2=1$ and $x_1x_2=a$. For divisibility, they must also be roots of $x^{13}+x+90$, so:

$$
x_1^{13}=-(x_1+90) \\ x_2^{13}=-(x_2+90)
$$

Multiplying the above and simplifying:

$$
x_1^{13}x_2^{13}=x_1x_2 +90(x_1+x_2)+90^2 \quad\iff\quad a^{13}-a-8190 = 0 \tag{1}
$$

It can be found that $(1)$ has the root $a=2$ by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) (or by previously proposed heuristics), and it can be verified that it satisfies the given problem since:

$$
x^{13} + x + 90 \\ = (x^2-x+2) (x^{11} + x^{10} - x^9 - 3 x^8 - x^7 + 5 x^6 + 7 x^5 - 3 x^4 - 17 x^3 - 11 x^2 + 23 x + 45)
$$

Factoring $a-2$ out of $(1)$ [leaves](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+a%5E13+-+a+-+90%5E2+-+90):

$$
a^{12} + 2 a^{11} + 4 a^{10} + 8 a^9 + 16 a^8 + 32 a^7 \\+ 64 a^6 + 128 a^5 + 256 a^4 + 512 a^3 + 1024 a^2 + 2048 a + 4095 = 0 \tag{2}
$$

In order to conclude that $a=2$ is the unique solution, what's left to show is that none of the $\,a\,$roots of $(2)$ corresponds to $\,x\,$ roots of $x^2-x+a=0$ which also satisfy $x^{13}+x+90=0$.

Indeed, eliminating $a$ between $(2)$ and $x^2-x+a=0$ by way of [polynomial resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition) gives [a $24^{th}$ degree polynomial in $x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+a%5E12+%2B+2+a%5E11+%2B+4+a%5E10+%2B+8+a%5E9+%2B+16+a%5E8+%2B+32+a%5E7+%2B+64+a%5E6+%2B+128+a%5E5+%2B+256+a%5E4+%2B+512+a%5E3+%2B+1024+a%5E2+%2B+2048+a+%2B+4095,+x%5E2+-+x+%2B+a,+a+%5D):

$$
x^{24} - 12 x^{23} + 64 x^{22} - 198 x^{21} + 389 x^{20} - 502 x^{19} + 436 x^{18} - 276 x^{17} \\ + 139 x^{16} - 24 x^{15} - 16 x^{14} - 46 x^{13} - x^{12} + 90 x^{11} + 92 x^{10} - 88 x^9 \\ - 272 x^8 - 96 x^7 + 448 x^6 + 640 x^5 - 256 x^4 - 1536 x^3 - 1024 x^2 + 2048 x + 4095
$$

It can be verified that the above has no common factor with $x^{13}+x+90$ by [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Wow.............!

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thanks, I guess ;-) The question got me curious enough to brute-force it, but I'll still be the first one to upvote an elegant, more "clever" proof of uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2-x+a|x^{13}+x+90$$
Hoping you may get lucky finding an 'integer' $a$, here is a simple shortcut
When $x=0$, you want $a | 90$
When $x=1$, you want $a | 92$

Can you guess $a$ that satisfies both above requirements

Answer (score 2):

As remarked by @rsadhvika, $a=\pm 1 $ or $\pm 2$. If $a=-2$ then the polynomial has $-1$ as a root, this gives a contradiction. If $a=+1$ let $x=2$ this gives a non divisiblity, and if $a=-1$, let $x=-2$, another non divisibility. So $a=2$.

Comment: `As remarked by @rsadhvika` That was qualified with "*hoping you may get lucky finding an 'integer' a*", which gave good insight, but not a definitive proof that $\,a\,$ *must* be an integer.

Comment: @dvx It must be an integer, this is just Gauss's lemma.

Comment: As polynomials, $\,x - \sqrt{2} \mid x^2 - 2\,$ for example, though $\,\sqrt{2}\,$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Is cheating allowed?

```
>> P=[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 90]

P =

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    90

>> r=roots(P)

r =

   1.3740 + 0.3391i
   1.3740 - 0.3391i
   1.0583 + 0.9391i
   1.0583 - 0.9391i
   0.5000 + 1.3229i
   0.5000 - 1.3229i
  -0.1721 + 1.4029i
  -0.1721 - 1.4029i
  -0.8036 + 1.1618i
  -0.8036 - 1.1618i
  -1.4119 + 0.0000i
  -1.2507 + 0.6555i
  -1.2507 - 0.6555i

>> r(5)*r(6)

ans =

    2.0000
```

So we found all the roots of the polynomial and selected the $2$ roots that added to $1$ so as to match the linear term of the quadratic factor. Then their product was $a=2$.